# Ethereum crowdsale tutorial code doesn't work on remix

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, remix, crowdsale, tutorials

I took [the crowdsale code from the tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale), copied the whole contract code and pasted it to [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) (with Rinkeby testnet), and I'm getting straight an error:

```
browser/contract.sol:52:25: ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen'
       emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
                        ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is strange. I've tried what you've posted and i only get the constructor warning. Could you add more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong compiler version. The `emit` keyword was added in Solidity version 0.4.21 - if you use any version below that you either have to remove the `emit` keyword (the event should work just fine without it then) or upgrade to a newer version.

Remix should support a recent enough compiler.